# Merging 3 files into 1 large file, while appending to specific lines in Python

Tags: python, file, merge

I have 3 large files, each containing similar content, but not the same. The first part is the token, and the second part is a dictionary that has an integer for the document ID, as well as the occurrences it has for that specific document. My problem is, I can't store everything into memory, and I need to dump into files multiple times as the data is extremely large. For example:

File1:

```
token1;{"1": 5, "2": 5, "4": 5}
token2;{"2": 3, "3": 4}
token3;{"1": 4, "5": 1, "6": 6}
```

File2:

```
token4;{"7": 2, "9": 1, "12": 2}
token5;{"8": 3, "11": 1, "12": 2}
token2;{"9": 2, "12": 2}
```

File3:

```
token1;{"13": 1, "14": 2}
token6;{"14": 1, "16": 2, "17": 1}
token7;{"14": 1, "17": 2, "18": 1, "19", 3}
```

Final contents I wish to have in the final file:

```
token1;{"1": 5, "2": 5, "4": 5, "13": 1, "14": 2}
token2;{"2": 3, "3": 4, "9": 2, "12": 2}
token3;{"1": 4, "5": 1, "6": 6}
token4;{"7": 2, "9": 1, "12": 2}
token5;{"8": 3, "11": 1, "12": 2}
token6;{"14": 1, "16": 2, "17": 1}
token7;{"14": 1, "17": 2, "18": 1, "19", 3}
```

The duplicate tokens I wish to have updated, as well as adding all new tokens to one single file. I can't load everything into memory, but I can go through each line 1 by 1 even if it takes a really long time. (this time efficiency isn't of highest priority). Any guide in the right direction is greatly appreciated! Thanks :)
P.S. I am writing this in Python

Comment: Presumably you should use a database.

Comment: @mkrieger1 unfortunately, as this is part of a school assignment, we were told not to use databases. Why? I am not sure either, I would have loved to know, but I can't use a database

Comment: How large is "extremely large"?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
This is a straightforward merge of sorted sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed a break so...

```py
from io import StringIO
import json

data = [
    '''\
token1;{"1": 5, "2": 5, "4": 5}
token2;{"2": 3, "3": 4}
token3;{"1": 4, "5": 1, "6": 6}
''',
    '''\
token4;{"7": 2, "9": 1, "12": 2}
token5;{"8": 3, "11": 1, "12": 2}
token2;{"9": 2, "12": 2}
''',
    '''\
token1;{"13": 1, "14": 2}
token6;{"14": 1, "16": 2, "17": 1}
token7;{"14": 1, "17": 2, "18": 1, "19": 3}
''',
]

out = {}
for text in data:
    f = StringIO(text)
    for line in f:
        key, s = line.split(';', 1)
        d = json.loads(s)
        out.setdefault(key, {}).update(d)

for key in sorted(out, key=lambda t: int(t[5:])):
    s = json.dumps(out[key])
    print(f"{key};{s}")
```

Replace `data` and the `StringIO()` instances with your file objects.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer. I did not notice the OP's comment re "can't store everything into memory". Too busy to edit my answer above but perhaps you can sort the lines on the tokens then process the data in batches, i.e., `token1` to `token100` would be one batch followed by `token101` to `token200`.

Comment: This led me to the answer I was looking for, so thank you!